# Accessing config variables stored in maps by key

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a variable in groovy like below:

```
project.Map
{
    time.'1 1   * ?' =  ['T1']
    time.'2 1   * ?' =  ['T2']
    templates.'T1'   =   ['Z','X','Y']
    templates.'T2'      =   ['Q']
}
```

Sorry but I am new to groovy ,when i try to access the individual
variable values in project.map  how do i access them

i tried something like below

```
log.info(grailsApplication.config.project.Map.time[1]) 
log.info(grailsApplication.config.project.Map.get('time.'2 1   * ?'' ))
log.info(grailsApplication.config.project.Map.get('time[0]' ))
log.info(grailsApplication.config.project.Map.time.get('1 1   * ?'))
```

but they all print null value or object references.how do i access values for
time and templates both within a for loop and without it.

Comment: What about `grailsApplication.config.project.Map.time.'2 1   * ?'`

Comment: yes i tried that ,when i do println grailsApplication.config.project.Map.time.'2 1 * ?' it prints this groovy.util.ConfigObject@1b3b7992 ..object reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#config for the ways the config is allowed to nest.  your outer syntax is especially mentioned to not be allowed:

> However, you can't nest after using the dot notation. In other words, this won't work:
>
> ```
> // Won't work!
> foo.bar {
>     hello = "world"
>     good = "bye"
> }
> ```

You have to write it as

```
project { Map { ... } }
```

The inner dotted parts (with the assignment) are ok (according to the doc)